# Is $R^2$ useful to determine the accuracy of a VARX model?

Tags: r-squared, vector-autoregression, accuracy, mape

I have a VARX model with 3 endogenous variables in 2nd differences. Each of 3 equations has very low $R^2$ (about 0,02), but the model gives good forecast (MAPEs are about 2%).

Can I neglect low $R^2$ in this case? What is the usual practice of using $R^2$ in time series models? Does this metric really capture the accuracy of such models?

Comment: See also ["Why not using the R squared to measure forecast accuracy?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195387/why-not-using-the-r-squared-to-measure-forecast-accuracy) and [R-squared to compare forecasting techniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99899/r-squared-to-compare-forecasting-techniques/99908#99908).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R^2$ is a goodness-of-fit measure; it measures how well the model fits the data that you have. What it does *not* do, is measure how well the model will fit the data that you don't have yet (i.e. how well it will *forecast*). In fact, you can trivially build a model for any dataset that will have $R^2=1$. This will be a large model which explains every bit of noise in your data, but it will not generalize to the future: forecasts will be poor. Bottom line is: if you want to forecast, look at forecast accuracy metrics, not $R^2$.

For your particular case, I would consider reducing the model and re-checking the MAPEs because it may improve your forecasts. I would also double-check the evidence for 2nd differences because that is somewhat unusual, depending on the subject domain.

Comment: Chris Haug, thank you so mush for answer!                                                         "if you want to forecast, look at forecast accuracy metrics, not R2" - new idea for me, in theory the higher R2 -> the better predictive power of a model -> the better forecast. Can you give an example of some papers about it?

Comment: "I would consider reducing the model and re-checking the MAPEs because it may improve your forecasts" - unfortunately, I can't reduce the quantity of endogenous variables, because it's important in this case.

Comment: "I would also double-check the evidence for 2nd differences because that is somewhat unusual, depending on the subject domain" - the 2st lag has better MAPE for this model (compared the 1st lag)

Comment: @Elena Sorry that wasn't clear, by "reducing" I meant setting some of the coefficients to zero, not removing endogenous variables.